# Referencing shared project within solution structure

Tags: c#, class-library, project-reference, shared-project

I'm trying to resolve problem with referencing shared project within couple class libraries.

Inside solution the references between projects are:

- Class library A -> SharedProject
- Class library B -> SharedProject
- Class library C -> SharedProject
- Class library C -> Class library A
- Class library C -> Class library B

In shared project I have only one class with logic, that I want to share, so in each class library project I'm using same class from shared project. But after build i get folowing error in Class library C:

The type 'same class' exists in both Class library A and Class library B

Is there a way to make this work, or shoul I replace shared project with classic class library?

Comment: Just make sure both class are under different namespace, problem solved.

Comment: Each class library has different namespace, the class within shared project has specific namespace, but it is shared among other libraries

Comment: Of course the same type exists. You compiled it into each DLL. It's in A, B, *and* C. See marked duplicate for details as to how this differs from referencing a common, standalone DLL across multiple projects. The shared project feature is there to facilitate sharing of code in scenarios where a DLL compiled once won't work (e.g. targeting completely different platforms). Personally, I would still just compile the DLL for each platform, but VS offers this feature that incorporates the whole code into the referencing project. It's more like adding existing files as a link, than a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'shared project' is effectively a way of sharing the source code between multiple projects without having to build a DLL (like in a class library). You can think of it as literally copy pasting the source code of SharedProject into Class library A and Class library B.

It should be fairly obvious at this point then that Class library A and Class library B do have the same classes defined in SharedProject, however they *both define* them, rather than both *referencing* the same classes.

Your initial intuition is correct, the correct way to do it is to replace it with a class library, which is exactly what it's for. You'll then have a SharedProject.dll that both A and B reference, and then C will reference A.dll, B.dll and SharedProject.dll, and it should all be fine (barring version mismatches).